# residue theorem for integrals with limits other than $-\infty$, $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

With the residue theorem, integrals such as $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {dx}{(1+x^2)} $ can be solved. Can this method also be used to calculate integrals such as

$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac {dx}{\sqrt{x^5+x^3+1} }$$

or

$$\int\limits_{0}^{1} e^x \tan(x)\,dx?$$

Comment: It's not the residue theorem that "solves" the integrals, it's the clever way of choosing contours.

Comment: For the first integral, yes in principle, although you need to find the roots of the radicand in the denominator because they are branch points that must not lie in the interior of an integration region defined by a contour.  For the second integral, I am afraid that there is no likely useful contour because the integration region has no endpoints at branch points or other singularities.

Comment: Could a transformation to the interval [0,oo] help ?

Comment: Numerical methods are better to this end. The Maple command $$evalf(Int(1/sqrt(x^5+x^3+1), x = 0 .. infinity), 25)  $$ outputs $1.414724796679884958409897 \neq \sqrt{2} $ and $$evalf(Int(exp(x)*tan(x), x = 0 .. 1), 25) $$ produces $ 1.265376481211212655430795$.